# Do special gem stats count gems created or gems matched?

Tags: bejeweled-3

The stats menu in Bejeweled 3 has entries for special gems (Flame Gems, Star Gems, Hypercubes). These special gems are created with specific types of matches (ie: 4 gems in a row creates 1 flame gem)

Are these stats counting how many special gems I've created or how many special gems I've matched? In other words, will the stats increase if I create a flame gem but never use it in a match?

[image: Bejeweled 3 stats]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The special gem stats count how many times a special gem type is used, either from being used in a match or destroyed by another special gem.

I tested this in Zen Mode. Matching 4 gems to create a flame gem did not affect my stats. Using a hypercube to destroy a flame gem incremented increased both the flame gem and hypercube stats by 1.